# I want to drag a mouse across a chart using selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to drag my cursor across a chart using pixel locations. Although after the second option is called, the cursor is no longer on the screen.

I tried action_reset() to reset the values to 0 and then called move_by_offset(290, 400) but this failed.

And I tried just adding move_by_offset(10, 0). But this also failed. I have read the documentation but don't see where I am going wrong?

Is there another method I should be implementing before tyring to move onto the next action?

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
  
    # setup automation
    action.move_by_offset(280, 400)    # 11px to the right, 20px to bottom
    action.perform()

    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot_4.png")

    action.move_by_offset(290, 400)  # 11px to the right, 20px to bottom
    action.perform()
    driver.implicitly_wait(11)

    driver.save_screenshot("screenshot_5.png")
```

Comment: `And I tried just adding move_by_offset(10, 0). But this also failed.` What do you mean it "failed", is there some error?

Isn't your second action telling the cursor to move again, so I'm not surprised it ends up offscreen?

Answer (score 0):

First, move_by_offset moves your cursor based on its **current** position.

```
action.move_by_offset(280, 400) # This actually moved your cursor 280 to the right
```

As to why simply using 10 fails... It could be a number of things related to where your cursor is initially located.

First, make sure to maximize your driver window since your offset can be overshooting your target if the window is too small.

If you want to move your cursor across a chart it's easier to first move to the element where your chart resides. I personally just use a move_to_element_with_offset that moves my cursor to the upper left corner of the chart element. Then use the width of the element to loop as an upper bound.

```
hover_area_css = "#some css selector"
hover_area_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,hover_area_css)
""" alternatively  hover_area_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, hover_area_css))
    )"""

# this goes to the upper left corner of the element, and goes to the right one px.
# I also go slightly downward in case the hover action doesn't occur at the boundary

actions = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(hover_area_element, 1, 2)
actions.perform()
# you might need to sleep a bit prior to continuing 

time.sleep(2)
# the size attribute contains dimension information of the element
width = hover_area_element.size["width"]

x_scroll = ActionChains(driver)

for i in range(width):
   try:
       # some func that captures the tooltip data for example
    # handle when tooltip no longer appears (you're off the chart)    
   except NoSuchElementException:
       break
   # you can also take the width and divide it by the number of x-axis ticks in the chart and use that as the offset for a rough estimate.

   x_scroll.move_by_offset(1,0)
   x_scroll.perform()
```